# Finding a string between strings in efficient way

Tags: c

Using a micro processor, i am running out of memory , and i have to do this in a very efficient and safe way.

So i have some data coming from server, and i have to find its header . So for example :

```
char *meida="+IPD,0,206:GET /setWifi:home:0545881255 HTTP/1.1  Host: 192.168.4.1" ;
```

I need to get only `setWifi:home:0545881255` .

`strstr` finds occurrence of string in a sentence. How can i use it to find the sentence between 2 words ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** now extracts the phrase between two keywords.

On the assumption that the data you read in is *not* a string literal, it can be modified. This code finds the location of the first keyword, skips past it, then finds the next keyword, and truncates the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){
    char meida[] ="+IPD,0,206:GET /setWifi:home:0545881255 HTTP/1.1  Host: 192.168.4.1";
    char *keyworda = "GET /";
    char *keywordb = " HTTP/";
    char *aptr, *bptr;

    aptr = strstr(meida, keyworda);
    if (aptr != NULL) {
        aptr += strlen(keyworda);       // skip past first keyword
        bptr = strstr(aptr, keywordb);
        if (bptr != NULL) {
            *bptr = '\0';               // truncate
            printf("%s\n", aptr);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
setWifi:home:0545881255
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: But it's not extracting the substring between the two strings.

Comment: @iharob indeed: OP should have made clear *what two words* he wants the between of.

Comment: Are you mad because I downvoted your answer?, it's not wrong but it's not what the OP wanted, although now I agree, The OP doesn't seem to be clear about what their requirements are. I actually think that it's very well written.

Comment: well, I downvoted, too, and this is nothing personal. I just think questions shouldn't be answered as long as they remain unclear.

Comment: @iharob not mad, I just don't think it's PC when you have submitted your own answer. Anyway, thanks for pointing out: edited.

Comment: @Curnelious I have no idea, where you're coming from (maybe PHP? pun intended ...) but serious programmers have a thing for conciseness and accuracy. And this in fact helps you "creating products". You're just "sloppy" and still people try to help you with answers without even knowing the exact requirements. But you go on and insult these trying to get YOU to actually *define* your requirements. Just saying you're on the wrong path here.

Comment: @WeatherVane retracting my downvote, it's just not fair to let a poor question "infect" your attempt to answer helpfully.

Comment: I would upvote (and I did) it even if I submit my answer if I think it's good, and I do think it's good, just what I pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you can modify the input string or not, if you can the solution is even more efficient.

Here are two versions, one that copies the input string and one that modifies it in place returning the substring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *
substring_enclosed(char *const input, const char *const left, const char *const right)
{
    char *result;
    char *tail;
    result = strstr(input, left);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* At this point `result' points to the occurrance of `left', skip
     * the same number of characters of `left' and you are there 
     */
    result += strlen(left);
    tail = strstr(result, right);
    if (tail != NULL)
        tail[0] = '\0';
    return result;
}

char *
substring_enclosed_const(const char *const input, const char *const left, const char *const right)
{
    char *result;
    char *tail;
    char *copy;

    copy = strdup(input);
    if (copy == NULL)
        return NULL;

    result = strstr(copy, left);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* At this point `result' points to the occurrance of `left', skip
     * the same number of characters of `left' and you are there 
     */
    result += strlen(left);

    /* You have to call `free' later and you cannot do it on the 
     * pointer that is a result of arithmetic above, you need the
     * one returned by `strdup()' 
     */
    memmove(copy, result, strlen(result) + 1);

    tail = strstr(result, right);
    if (tail != NULL)
        tail[0] = '\0';

    return copy;
}

int
main(void)
{
    const char *meida = "+IPD,0,206:GET /setWifi:home:0545881255 HTTP/1.1  Host: 192.168.4.1";
    char writeable[] = "+IPD,0,206:GET /setWifi:home:0545881255 HTTP/1.1  Host: 192.168.4.1";
    char *substr;

    substr = substring_enclosed_const(meida, "GET /", " HTTP");
    if (substr != NULL)
    {
        puts(substr);
        free(substr);
    }

    substr = substring_enclosed(writeable, "GET /", " HTTP");
    if (substr != NULL)
        puts(substr);

    return 0;
}
```